# Extract multiple string matches with a regular expression

Tags: objective-c, ios, regex

I'm trying to extract multiple parts of a string based on a regular expression like (mymatch1|mymatch2|mymatch3)

I found a function like below, that helps me to extract a match.

```
NSRange range = [myString rangeOfString:myRegex options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
```

But there is any function that can return a set of ranges? or directly the array of substrings matched?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the documentation for NSRegularExpression, methods -[NSRegularExpression enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:]

Comment: Thank you, that's it! Sorry i was lost with NSPredicates and this function of strings.